# How to disable or hide WordPress.com as a social media login option for Jetpack Comments

Tags: wordpress, plugins, comments, jetpack

I am looking for a method to hide or remove WordPress from the login options in Jetpack Comments.

Here is a screenshot of the default comment form with Jetpack Comments enabled.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEPvq.png

Thank you!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjHxb.png)

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: a#postas-wordpress {display:none !important}
it not works